# Re-Hosted workflow Designer "Browse and Select a .NET type"

Tags: .net, types, workflow-foundation-4

I already have implemented a re-hosted workflow designer. My problem is when

1. Clicking on the Variable Tab
2. type a variable name let's call it Q
3. Click down arrow to select a Variable Type for variable named Q
4. Select "Browse For Type" from the drop down menu
5. A Window pops up named "Browse and Select a .NET type"  with a UI control where you can type the variable Type name
6. In the read only body of this window all the referenced assemblies are listed

My questions are : where in the workflow designer code these assemblies are added to this list and therefore I want to know why this specific assembly (my custom activity) is displayed more than once.  All the other referenced assemblies are referred to only once.

Any help is very welcome.

Thanks